# Rails: Failing test with an ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, tdd

I have a pretty straightforward User model and want to test it:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And here is what I have in test/models/user_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "shoudl always pass" do
    assert true
  end

end
```

The command `rake test` throws out the following error:

```
  1) Error:
UserTest#test_shoudl_always_pass:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (980190962, null, null, null, 2015-10-12 09:10:40, 2015-10-12 09:10:40).
: INSERT INTO "keywords" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2015-10-12 09:10:40', '2015-10-12 09:10:40', 980190962)
```

Why I'm getting such a strange error on an almost empty test case and how to fix it?

Comment: The error seems to rather be related to `keywords` table with a non-null `name` column. @PeterR may be on the right track about fixtures being to blame for this.

Answer (score 9):

Solved! Commented the line `fixtures :all` in test_helper.rb

Comment: Wonderful, it helps, although I don't know the mechanism behind it, anyway thanks, friend.

Answer (score 2):

Usually updating your fixtures/users.yml can fix this. Either comment them out or make sure that they both create records with unique names

Comment: I commented out all fixtures, there is nothing there. Didn't solve the issue.